# How can I find if firebaseAuthIsReady with v3.0.0?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux-firebase

What is the alternative in react-redux-firebase with v3.0.0 to find out if auth is ready - to render for the first time? Problem in this case is that store doesn't contain firebaseAuthIsReady or am I missing something?

```
//ReactReduxFirebaseProvider v3.0.0
const rrfConfig = { 
  userProfile: 'users',
  attachAuthIsReady: true,
  firebaseStateName: 'firebase'
}

//const store = configureStore(initialState, history, rrfConfig);
const store = configureStore(initialState, history);


const rrfProps = {
  firebase,
  config: rrfConfig,
  dispatch: store.dispatch,
  createFirestoreInstance
}

const MOUNT_NODE = document.getElementById('root')
//store.firebaseAuthIsReady.then(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
          <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <App />
          </ConnectedRouter>
        </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
      </Provider>
    </MuiThemeProvider>,
    MOUNT_NODE
  );
```

Comment: promise attachment was removed in new version

Comment: It there any other way to accomplish this in v3.0.0? @sbtgE

Comment: mapStateToProps auth from firebase - state.firebase.auth, and then you can use isLoaded(this.props.auth) function from rrf

Answer (score 5):

```
 //For React Redux Firebase v3.0.*      
        import React from 'react';
        import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
        import App from './App';
        import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
        import { Provider, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
        import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
        import rootReducer from './myproject/rootReducer';
        import { createFirestoreInstance } from 'redux-firestore';
        import { ReactReduxFirebaseProvider, isLoaded } from 'react-redux-firebase';
        import firebase from './myproject/config/fbConfig';       

           const rrfConfig = {}

           const store = createStore(
               rootReducer, 
                compose(
                 applyMiddleware(thunk)   // if you are using thunk 
                  )
            )

            const rrfProps = {
                  firebase,
                  config: rrfConfig,
                  dispatch: store.dispatch,
                  createFirestoreInstance
               }

           function AuthIsLoaded({ children }) {
                    const auth = useSelector(state => state.firebase.auth)
                    if (!isLoaded(auth)) return <div>Loading Screen...</div>;
                        return children
                }

    ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
                     <AuthIsLoaded><App /> </AuthIsLoaded></ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
            </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

See react-redux-firebase Doc: [Wait For Auth To Load on http://react-redux-firebase.com/](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/recipes/auth.html#wait-for-auth-to-load)

Answer (score 0):

The way of implementing that is the new versions is mentioned here in their docs:
http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/recipes/auth.html#wait-for-auth-to-load

1. import the isLoaded from "react-redux-firebase" like this:

   ```
   import { isLoaded } from "react-redux-firebase"
   ```
2. create a function that returns a loader spin or something while the
   data is not loaded yet:

   ```
   function AuthIsLoaded({ children }) {  
   const auth = useSelector((state) => state.firebase.auth);   if
   (!isLoaded(auth))
       return (
         <Wrapper>
           <Loader />
         </Wrapper>
       );   
   return children; }
   ```
3. wrap your app inside the AuthIsLoaded component like this:

   ```
   <AuthIsLoaded>
       <App />
   </AuthIsLoaded>
   ```

and this will work just like the firebaseAuthReady function.

Comment: When answers go through the review queues one of the options for marking something as very low quality (should be deleted) is when an answer consists of only a link and would be useless to someone in the future if that link were to break. The way to fix this is to make sure that the answer is self contained, and uses the link only to provide additional information.

Comment: understood, changes have made!

Answer (score -1):

```
import { isLoaded, isEmpty } from 'react-redux-firebase';
```

See: http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/recipes/auth.html